# How do you determine what convolutional layers look for in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

This is my first post, so I'm sorry if I'm doing something wrong. I'm a beginner when it comes to machine learning. I want to create an accurate model with the cifar10 dataset. I've learned that a Conv2D layer looks for a specific thing in an image classification model. But how do I know what the layer is looking for? I'm not sure if I make sense here, or if anything I've learned so far is true could someone help me out in understanding how layers work in tensorfow?

Comment: Hi Sea Bear, welcome to StackOverflow. To help us help you, provide more information about your problem. Show us your code, tell us what you have tried, and provide links to libraries/datasets you are using.

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to learn more about asking a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolutional layers extract features from images. They apply a filter to images and output a feature map. Then, one may add dense layers afterwards to obtain labels from these features.

Conv2D is just a 2d convolution used with 2d images - this means that the kernel is 2d also.

[image]

Here are a few helpful links: https://machinelearningmastery.com/convolutional-layers-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/

https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-introduction-to-convolutional-neural-networks-cdf8d3077bac